# Cannot download completed gz files from internet using download.file function

Tags: r

I want to use the download.file function in R to download all gz files from http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gwas/summary_statistics/KettunenJ_27005778_GCST003664/

Here is the code I used:

```
url <- "http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gwas/summary_statistics/KettunenJ_27005778_GCST003664/"
## query the url to get all the file names ending in '.gz'
zips <- XML::getHTMLLinks(
  url, 
  xpQuery = "//a/@href['.gz'=substring(., string-length(.) - 2)]"
)
zips
## create a new directory 'myzips' to hold the downloads
dir.create("C:/Work/GWAS/download")
## save the current directory path for later
wd <- getwd()
## change working directory for the download
setwd("C:/Work/GWAS/download")
## create all the new files
file.create(zips)
## download them all
lapply(paste0(url, zips), function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
## reset working directory to original
setwd(wd)
```

When I run the code the first file would be downloaded 22.5 MB out of 290.2 MB, then tried to download the second file, then tried the third one. The results and warning were:

```
lapply(paste0(url, zips), function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
trying URL 'http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gwas/summary_statistics/KettunenJ_27005778_GCST003664/Summary_statistics_MAGNETIC_AcAce.txt.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 304261893 bytes (290.2 MB)
downloaded 22.5 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gwas/summary_statistics/KettunenJ_27005778_GCST003664/Summary_statistics_MAGNETIC_Ace.txt.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 317862935 bytes (303.1 MB)
downloaded 3.9 MB

trying URL 'http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gwas/summary_statistics/KettunenJ_27005778_GCST003664/Summary_statistics_MAGNETIC_Ala.txt.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 318129968 bytes (303.4 MB)

Warning messages:
1: In download.file(x, basename(x)) :
  downloaded length 23618412 != reported length 304261893
2: In download.file(x, basename(x)) :
  downloaded length 4039024 != reported length 317862935
```

Anyone know what is the problem, and how to fix it? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced the error and found changing the default timeout to `options(timeout=6000)` solved the problem:

```
options(timeout = 6000)
url <- "http://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gwas/summary_statistics/KettunenJ_27005778_GCST003664/"
## query the url to get all the file names ending in '.gz'
zips <- XML::getHTMLLinks(
  url, 
  xpQuery = "//a/@href['.gz'=substring(., string-length(.) - 2)]"
)
zips
## create a new directory 'myzips' to hold the downloads
dir.create("C:/Work/GWAS/download")
## save the current directory path for later
wd <- getwd()
## change working directory for the download
setwd("C:/Work/GWAS/download")
## create all the new files
file.create(zips)
## download them all
lapply(paste0(url, zips), function(x) download.file(x, basename(x)))
## reset working directory to original
setwd(wd)
```